# Where to ask a question about a .NET Framework error

Tags: discussion

I have a question about a .NET Framework error which might be related to installation of .NET Framework 4.0 full version. The error is:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorepe.dll is either
>   not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error ...

On that client machine my application developed in .NET 4.0 works perfectly, but another application designed in .NET Framework 3.5 gives this error.

I have some more questions details, which I would add with my *actual* question, and I didn't add it here for meta.

Now, I am not sure where to ask this question. Is it on topic on Stack Overflow or should I ask that on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: Certainly not serverfault. It's [su] or *maybe* [so].

Comment: Stack Overflow seems to be the appropriate place; as programmers would be better suited to troubleshoot a problem with this than non programmers would (and the problem directly relates to programming).  Your criteria is the same anywhere: Provide enough detail that we can reproduce your issue; and write clearly about what the issue is.

Comment: The only time this would be a super user question is if its some 3rd party program.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just posted the question on Stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592443/net-framework-mscorpe-dll-error